# I'm trying to insert new record but it gives error as Line: 7, Column: 1 System.StringException: Invalid id: objcus.id

Tags: insert, dmlexception

```
Apex_Customer__c objcus=new Apex_Customer__c();
objcus.Name='Test ABC';
insert objcus;//it will creat new customer records
Apex_Invoice__c objnewinvoice=new Apex_Invoice__c();
objnewinvoice.Apex_Status__c='Pending';
objnewinvoice.Apex_Amount_Paid__c=1000;
objnewinvoice.Apex_Customer__c='objcus.id';
insert objnewinvoice;
system.debug('The customer we added is +objcus+ and the corresponding invoices are +objnewinvoice');
```

Answer (score 2):

The variable should not be in quotes, as this makes it a String. When cast back to an Id, it is found to be invalid, thus causing the rrror.

```
objnewinvoice.Apex_Customer__c=objcus.id;
```